# Getting common name efficiently from tls certificate with openssl

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have a pointer to TLS certificate and I need to get commonName property;

I at first create X509 object with function d2i_X509 like ;

```
x = d2i_X509(NULL, &p, certificate_lenght);
if (x == NULL)
    return https_failure;
```

Than I call function X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID for getting commonName

```
X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(X509_get_subject_name(x),NID_commonName, hc->https_domain_name, 256);
```

It works for me but I am worried about performance . I think, all certificate object is parsed when I only need commonName . Is there any better method for getting commonName with more efficiency .

Comment: Actually, if you want to authenticate an HTTPS website, you'll need to look for the Subject Alternative Names extensions (of DNS type) first, and only fall back onto the CN if there aren't any.

Comment: You shouldn't speculate about possible inefficiencies without doing actual measurements.

Comment: I didn't say something is inefficient. Performance is important for my case . I want to understand if there is more efficient way or not .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no more efficient way using OpenSSL high-level API. If you are really interested in having the best performance possible, you'll need to use the low-level ASN.1 parsing API.
But keep in mind that you cannot fully validate a certificate without parsing it entirely, so I would be concerned with the security implications of only extracting the CN.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.It is very helpfull . For low level asn.1 API I checked for "http://lionet.info/asn1c/compiler.html" but it seems I need to generate a skeleton(c file) and to generate this file I must write certificate in ASN.1 format and compile it via ASN1 compiler. Did I misunderstood or is there any easy way out for using low level ASN1 api .

Comment: Also validating certificate is not important for my case I just need to get servername.